# Can you tell if a vertex attribute is enabled from within a vertex shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl, vertex-shader, vertex-attributes

I was wondering if there was a way to tell if a vertex attribute is enabled from within a vertex shader? I know that if the vertex attribute is disabled all the values will be treated as 0.0, so I could do a test like the following:

```
if (attribute == 0)
{
    // Do something different to normal.
}
else
{
    // Use the attribute.
}
```

But this has the obvious problem for the case that the attribute is enabled and the value is just set to 0 (it will be treated as if it's disabled)!

The other solution would be to just use a uniform variable that states whether or not to use the attribute, but I wondered if there was anything built into GLSL that would do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No there isn't.

Pass a boolean uniform yourself to emulate it.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I went with. Would be nice if this could become a GLSL feature in the future!

Answer (score 18):

FYI:

> I know that if the vertex attribute is disabled all the values will be treated as 0.0, so I could do a test like the following:

That is not true. If an attribute is disabled, its value comes from regular OpenGL state. Namely, the state set by the [`glVertexAttrib`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glVertexAttrib) functions. So it is perfectly legal to have these kinds of "constant attributes" sent to shaders.

That's why the API doesn't have a way for a shader to tell if an attribute is "disabled". A "disabled" attribute may still have meaningful data.

Comment: @OP So your solution of checking for a specific "not enabled"-value could be adapted to use a value different than 0, one that isn't a "real" attribute value that could occur otherwise, by just setting `glVertexAttrib` to this value. So you don't need an additional boolean.

Comment: Oh! Does the `glVertexAttrib` function set the value that will be used for every vertex? So for example if I called `glVertexAttrib1f(3, -1.0f)` then all the vertex attributes at location 3 would be set to -1.0f?

Comment: @JamesBedford: Yes. Unless that attribute's array is enabled.